# Android how to write audio track to sd card as mp3 or other audio format

Tags: android, audio, mp3, sd-card

basically i need to change record voice then add effect to voice then share it with effect
in short share voice with adding effect
    void playRecord() {

```
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "testaudio.pcm");
        // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        // "testaudio.3gp");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (file.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }



            dataInputStream.close();

            // int sampleFreq = (Integer) spFrequency.getSelectedItem();
            int sampleFreq = 11025;
            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            // audioTrack.reloadStaticData()
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this i need to save this audioTrack to my sd card as audio format like mp3 or waw

Comment: `AudioTrack` is a playback API. It's not used for recording or transcoding audio. If you need a WAV file, take the contents of your .pcm file, create a [WAV header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) for it, and write the header and the audio data to another file.

Comment: can you give detail information or some example?

Comment: The link I gave in my previous comment explains the header format and what the file is supposed to look like.

Comment: can you give alternate solution for this? basically i need to change record voice then add effect to voice then share it with effect

Comment: the problem is not solving by lib need some more help plz